# Find the general solution of the equation $x^{(5)} + 2x^{(4)} + 2x^{(3)} + 4x'' + x' + 2x = 100e^{-2t}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the equation $$x^{(5)} + 2x^{(4)} + 2x^{(3)} + 4x'' + x' + 2x = 100e^{-2t}.$$

I don't understand how solve such tasks. I know that I should solve $x^{(5)} + 2x^{(4)} + 2x^{(3)} + 4x'' + x' + 2x =0$ and then use $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ but I don't understand why and what I can do next. Can anyone show me solution with explanation, so that I can solve the next tasks on my own?

Comment: This is a fifth degree, constant coefficient, linear ODE. Have you tried second order linear, constant coefficient ODEs? That is, where the highest derivative is $x''$? Are you familiar with the process there? Because the process is basically the same, except you have to find the roots of a degree $5$ polynomial instead of a degree $2$ polynomial.

Comment: You have to find the roots $r$ of the characteristic polynomial i.e solving $r^5 + 2r^4 + 2r^3 + 4r^2 + r+2=0$. Then each of the roots gives you a solution of the homogeneous system. Then you find the general solution of the homogeneous equation using the fact that the solution is a subspace of dimension $5$. Finally you solve the equation with non-zero RHS by finding a particular solution.

Comment: Haven't you seen Laplace Transform ? It is the appropriate tool !

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$x^{(5)} + 2x^{(4)} + 2x^{(3)} + 4x'' + x' + 2x = 100e^{-2t}.$$
It's easier to solve this:
$$y'''' + 2y'' + y= 100e^{-2t}$$
Where $y=x' + 2x $.
$$y'''' + 2y'' + y= 0$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^4+2r^2+1=0$$
$$(r^2+1)^2=0$$

Comment: Though the initial degree $5$ characteristic polynomial would factor similarly to $(r+2)(r^2+1)^2$, so initial ODE might also be dealt with directly.

Comment: Yes you're right  oce you get the factorization yes @zwim

Answer (score 0):

Solving these problems has a straightforward step and a somewhat tricky/intuitive step. Here is how we break the problem in two:

We begin with $L(x)=f(t)$ , where $L$ is all the differential operations on the function $x$ in the left-hand-side and $f$ is a function of the independent variable $t$ in the right-hand-side.

Now, if we find two functions $x_h$ and $x_p$ such that $L(x_h)=0$ and $L(x_p)=f(t)$ then we can say that $x=x_h+x_p$ is a solution of our differential equation (why?).

Finding $x_h$ is relatively easy for problems with constant coefficients: as you mentioned, we begin with assuming $x=e^{rt}$. Then $x'=re^{rt}$ , which helps us convert the differential equation to an algebraic equation for $r$ (how?). We refer to $L(x_h)=0$ the homogeneous equation.

Finding $x_p$ on the other hand, is somewhat tricky. In simple cases like this problem, the function $f(t)$ gives a helpful hint. For example, here we know we should be looking for some function of $e^{-2t}$. Why? Because it is not intuitive that by applying differential operations on other functions (for example, polynomials, or even exponential functions without $-2t$ in their exponent) we can come up with $e^{-2t}$. So, we may have a candidate function to try. Now, here it is very important to make sure that this candidate is *not* one of the solutions of the homogeneous equation (why *not*?). In the unfortunate case that our candidate function *is* already a solution of the homogeneous equation, we apply a trick to build an independent class of functions. For cases where our candidate is an exponential function like $Ae^{\lambda t}$, we just multiply it by the independent variable to have $Ate^{\lambda t}$ (what shall we do if this latter is also a solution of the homogeneous equation?).

Finally, note that here we are looking for the *general* solution. That means our answer should include all possible solutions. To that end, note that if $x_i$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, then $c_i x_i$ is also a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Good luck.